# Posição da data para gráfico de Gantt do Google

Tags: php, google

Google Gráfico Timeline

Estou usando o gráfico de Gantt, lá da documentação do Google, segue imagem do meu gráfico a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que as datas do gráfico, fiquem no topo do gráfico, e não no rodapé.

Não encontrei nada na documentação, e todos os outros gráficos que olhei do google, apresentação no rodapé, como um padrão.

Documentação do Google:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#chart.draw

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#an-advanced-example

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

**Meu código:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container   = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart       = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable   = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string',   id: 'Position' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string',   id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date'  ,   id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date'  ,   id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        <?php
        while (!$rs->EOF){
            $html .= "
                      [
                          '{$dados['nome']}',                
                          '{$dados['etapa_nome']}',
                          new Date({$dados['data_inicial'][0]},
                          {$dados['data_inicial'][1]},
                          {$dados['data_inicial'][2]}),
                          new Date({$dados['data_final'][0]},
                          {$dados['data_final'][1]},
                          {$dados['data_final'][2]})
                      ]
                ,
            ";
            $rs->MoveNext();
        }
        $html = substr($html, 0, -1);
        echo $html;
        ?>
   ]); 
var options = {
    avoidOverlappingGridLines: false
  };
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
    </script>
```

**Alguém sabe qual parâmetro, e se tem como alterar a posição ?**

Answer (score 0):

Opa defina isso no seu options:

```
var options = {
   axes: {
      x: {
        0: {side: 'top'}
      }
    },
    avoidOverlappingGridLines: false
};
```

Que vai resolver :)

Comment: Não funcionou, coloquei este option e não deu, tu chegou a testar aí?

Comment: Testei mas em uma situação diferente pq o seu n da pra render ele. Coloca o seu com dados ficticios no fiddle q testamos nele